# ng-admin add a 'Create' button with default value based on filter

Tags: ng-admin

I have a list view, and a filter. Let's say the user filter by a reference object. and he see no records found, I'd like to offer him to create a new record, but to use the picked value from the filter as an initial value for the new record.

I can't figure out how,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from @François Zaninotto answer,

It's very simple, we just need to add this:

> default-values="search"

inside the ma-create directive, for each view we'd like it's creation to be based on filter results.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to override the `listView` template and write a custom directive.

Pointers:

- http://ng-admin-book.marmelab.com/doc/Theming.html#customizing-the-view-template-for-a-given-entity
- https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/bd734ba347add0c2aed6ab995585fb723b04cbd7/src/javascripts/ng-admin/Crud/list/listLayout.html